# Java - best way to call a method of each object in a collection

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a little 2D game / game engine in Java.

Each type of object which is the scene extends the class "Object" which has an abstract method "tick()". Furthermore there's a class called "Scene" which has a HashMap containing all the objects in the scene. I want the scene to call the method "tick()" of every object in the HashMap (60 times per second).

```
public class Scene {
  private HashMap<String, Object> objs; //HashMap containing all the objects

  private void tick() {
    for(Entry<String, Object> e : objs.entrySet()) {
      Object o = e.value();
      o.tick();
    }
  }

  [...]
}
```

Now I'm wondering if there is a better, more elegant way to achieve this. Maybe by creating an EventObject & EventListener or by using an Observable and make each object an Observer?

Comment: You can do `objs.values().forEach(value -> value.tick());`

Comment: What I would change first is the name of the class Object. You'll have constant clashes with the standard, auto-imported java.lang.Object class.

Comment: Ok so you think that using the for loop is the best / simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes I'm going to do that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (MyOb o: objs.values()) {
    o.tick();
}
```

You could also do this using the stream API:

```
objs.values().forEach(v -> v.tick());
```

Or even more compact:

```
objs.values().forEach(MyOb::tick);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
objs.forEach((k, v) -> v.tick());
```